I tried installing pfsense as a virtual machine on hyper-V , however i am not able to connect it over LAN to other Vms on the hyper-V
I set up a WAN and LAN for PFsense and LAN on other windows virtual machine. I gave the pfsense LAN as gateway address of Virtual LAN. I am not able to connect to internet over LAN.
I set IP Address in class of 192.168.9.x for WAN and 192.168.3.X for LAN. Where am i going wrong.

you need a public and private switch, the private is your virtual lan and the gateway is the ip from the pfsense fw on this nic, however it is offtopic for serverfault.com

I have configured WAN to get external connection and LAN to internal ,and it still dint work . Could you explain more in detail?

don't use internal, use private, internal has nat enabled while private is isolated. if your lan has 192.168.0.1 the ip then this is the gateway, your clients have 192.168.0.2 and above

I tried settng it as private but still dint work. I am not getting internet connection on the clients
